# assigning a function to Reader.onload

Tags: javascript, filereader

Can someone explain me what this last line of code `Reader.onload = someFunction` is doing. is it assigning a function to Reader.onload. what is the purpose of this assignment.

```
var reader = new window.FileReader(); 
reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
reader.onload = onReadAsDataURL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as *event registration*, you assign a function to the `onload` property of the `reader object`, usually several events will fire and there will be checks on properties such as `onload` to see if there's any function assigned to these properties. If so the function assigned to the relevant property will be executed.

It's actually quite straightforward, you *register* a function to a property, so that this function will be executed whenever the event for given property fires.

See [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) and [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) for more info on the subject

Comment: If you feel that my answer solved your question you can mark this answer as resolved, thanks!